# Delay before displaying unicode character in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, unicode, progressive-web-apps

I'm noticing a small delay in my Flutter code when displaying a Unicode character. With my demo code, there is a delay of a few milliseconds, but in a bigger code with more widgets to load, sometimes it can take half a second up to a whole second.

Is that a known problem? If so, is there also a known solution to this?

Find here the demo code to reproduce my issue:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter unicode demo',
      theme: ThemeData(

        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});
  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        title: const Text('Flutter unicode demo'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text(String.fromCharCode(0x1F600)),
        ),
      );
  }
}
```

And my Flutter doctor:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.16.2, on macOS 14.1.2 23B92 darwin-x64, locale fr)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.0.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.3)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.84.2)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[✓] Network resources

• No issues found!
```

Thanks for your help!